# Lyx margin settings for binding

Tags: lyx, margins

I would like to edit the lyx default settings in respect to page margins in order to allow for a larger binding margin. However, when I print two-sided I can not simply use a larger margin for the left border. Is there a way in Lyx to set a larger binding margin for a two-sided print?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Document->Preferences->Documentclass` and then use one of the KOMA-Script classes article, report or book (whatever you want). Into the classoptions insert `BCOR=1cm` or whatever you like. And be sure that you enabled the `twoside` option under the topic page layout.